# Can't get value of array inside computed property

Tags: ember.js

I'm having trouble with a computed property in Ember.

The problematic item is `timeZones`, which is set like this:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model(params) {
    return Ember.RSVP.hash({
      account: this.store.findRecord('account', params.id),
      timeZones: this.store.findAll('time-zone'), <------------ timeZones
      users: this.store.query('user', { by_account_id: params.id })
    });
  },

  setupController(controller, model) {
    this._super(controller, model.account);
    controller.set('users', model.users);
    controller.set('timeZones', model.timeZones);
  }
});
```

Then I have something called `selectedTimeZone` which looks like this:

```
  selectedTimeZone: Ember.computed('location.timezone', 'timeZones', function() {
    console.log(this.get('timeZones'));

    const timeZoneName = this.get('location.timezone');
    var result;

    this.get('timeZones').forEach(function(timeZone) {
      if (timeZone.name === timeZoneName) {
        console.log('yes'); // <------------------- never gets here
        result = timeZone;
      }
    });

    return result;
  }),
```

The problem is that `this.get('timeZones')` isn't really accessible inside the component. `timeZones` makes it to the template just fine. I'm populating a dropdown with `timeZones` right now. But when I `console.log` it, it just comes through as `Class`.

How can I get my hands on `timeZones` inside this computed property?

Answer (score 0):

actually most of this looks good, however some code is missing. Like is this a component or the controller, and if its a component how is the component invoked?

however one problem is obvious. `timeZone` obviously is a `ember-data` record, and so accessing `timeZone.name` is not a good idea. You should use embers `.get()`, either `timeZone.get('name')` or `Ember.get(timeZone, 'name')`.

Next your dependency key is wrong. Because you use the `name` of each `timeZone` you should replace the dependency key `timeZone` with `timeZone.@each.name`.

Finally a bit a smaller version of your CP using [`findBy`](https://emberjs.com/api/ember/2.14/classes/Ember.MutableEnumerable/methods/findBy?anchor=findBy):

```
selectedTimeZone: Ember.computed('location.timezone', 'timeZones.@each.name', function() {
  const timeZoneName = this.get('location.timezone');
  return this.get('timeZones').findBy('name', timeZoneName);
}),
```

If this is *not working* you should verify that the data are loaded successfully into the store with the ember inspector and verify that you pass the `timeZones` into the component with `timeZones=model.timeZones` when calling the component from your controller.